# Programmable Video twilio: How to reuse mediaStream

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Let say i already have acquired the stream using

```
var stream ;
navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true}, function(mediastream) {
    stream=mediastream;
});
```

Now how can i use `stream` when connecting to a room, I dont want Twilio to call `getUserMedia` again in `createLocalTracks` when i call `Twilio.Video.connect` api. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can use the stream you already collected. You just have to pass the tracks as an [option to `Video.connect`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/global.html#ConnectOptions) with the `tracks` key. There is an [example in the documentation](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/global.html#connect__anchor) which I have reproduced below:

```
var Video = require('twilio-video');
var token = getAccessToken();

// Connect with media acquired using getUserMedia()
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: true,
  video: true
}).then(function(mediaStream) {
  return Video.connect(token, {
    name: 'my-cool-room',
    tracks: mediaStream.getTracks()
  });
}).then(function(room) {
  room.on('participantConnected', function(participant) {
    console.log(participant.identity + ' has connected');
  });

  room.once('disconnected', function() {
    console.log('You left the Room:', room.name);
  });
});
```